# `Do` looping - break & output based on pattern

Tags: infinite-loop

I have the following loop that I would like to stop after the pattern repeats & output cycle length:

```
gamePairs[{a_, b_}] := If[a < b, {2 a, b - a}, {2 b, a - b}]
gamePlong[pair_] := 
Do[Print@Sort@Nest[gamePairs, pair, n]; If[Nest[gamePairs, pair, n][[1]] == 0 || 
Nest[gamePairs, pair, n][[2]] == 0, Break[]], {n, 10}]

gamePlong[{2, 28}]
```

Any hints would be most welcome :)

Comment: Do you wish to `Sow` desired results while continuing the loop or to `Return` from the loop when the desired results are obtained?

Comment: Ah, thanks - yes, `Return` would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

This `Module` stops after the first repetition of a pair and returns the list of pairs, sorted by the first element of the pairs.  It also `Print`s each element as it is computed, as before.

```
gamePlong[pair_] := Module[{tem, ltem, ans = {}}, 
  Do[tem = Sort@Nest[gamePairs, pair, n]; Print@tem; ltem = Length[ans]; ans = Union[ans, {tem}]; 
   If[ltem == Length[ans], Return[ans]], {n, 10}]]

gamePlong[{2, 28}]
(* {{2, 28}, {4, 26}, {8, 22}, {14, 16}} *)
```

**Update**

Note that the `Module` returns `Null`, if the end of the loop is reached before repetition occurs.  To have it return the entire list, change the code to

```
gamePlong[pair_] := Module[{tem, ltem, ans = {}}, 
  Do[tem = Sort@Nest[gamePairs, pair, n]; Print@tem; ltem = Length[ans]; ans = Union[ans, {tem}]; 
   If[ltem == Length[ans], Return[]], {n, 10}]; ans]
```

**Second Update**

If sorting is not desired, the following can be used:

```
gamePlong[pair_] := Module[{tem, ans = {}}, 
  Do[tem = Sort@Nest[gamePairs, pair, n]; Print@tem; If[Length[ans] == Length[Union[ans, {tem}]], 
  Return[]]; ans = Append[ans, tem], {n, 10}]; ans]

gamePlong[{2, 28}]
(* {{4, 26}, {8, 22}, {14, 16}, {2, 28}} *)
```

Comment: thank you very much, it looks great - will try to use as a template for understanding loop structures :)

Comment: Just noticed and fixed a transcription error in the first line of the `Module`.  Best wishes.

Comment: Yes, that's better :)

Comment: Don't know why, but I have to change semicolon to comma after curly brackets in `Module`

Comment: Evidently, I introduced a few typos when I moved `ans = {}` inside the initialization section of the `Module`.  Thanks for catching it.

Comment: It it possible to hide what is printed?

Comment: Better not to print it at all.  Just delete `Print@tem;` from the code.

Comment: for some reason that gives incorrect output

Comment: Gives the same output for me.  Whole `Module` should now be `gamePlong[pair_] := Module[{tem, ltem, ans = {}}, Do[tem = Sort@Nest[gamePairs, pair, n]; ltem = Length[ans]; ans = Union[ans, {tem}]; If[ltem == Length[ans], Return[]], {n, 10}]; ans]`

Comment: for me, the printed ouutput differs from the list

Comment: it is sorted by first elenent. Is there any way to restor printed output order?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps another way:

```
us[lst_] := Last@Reap[Sow[1, w[#]] & /@ lst, _, #1 /. w[a_] :> a &]
funs[u_] := us@Rest@NestWhileList[Sort@gamePairs[#] &, u, UnsameQ, All]
```

Test cases:

```
Grid[Table[{j, funs[j]}, {j, {{2, 28}, {2, 2}, {4, 20}, {5, 6}}}], 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]